# isotope filters + search with reset

Tags: jquery, search, reset, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make my isotope grid work with a reset where all filters & the search clear out and things go back to its original state before any interaction.

With what I have so far, things clear out to a certain degree, however, the "active" state of the "li" elements are not working - Also, I'm not a fan of what I had to do to get to at least this point...duplicating code, is there a better way to handle all this?

The issue I'm at right now is that if I have the grid set to "ALL" by default, then I type in text in search field, then select a filter, when I reset, the active state stays on the filter I selected when it shouldn't, it should go back to its default of "ALL" filter.  Hopefully I explained this well enough :/

Any help on this is appreciated.

JS:

```
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
        var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
        return searchResult && buttonResult;
    }
});
$('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope();
});
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
}));
// change active class on buttons
$('.directory_menu ul').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $( this ).addClass('active');
    });
});
// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
        var args = arguments;
        var _this = this;
        function delayed() {
            fn.apply( _this, args );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
    };
}

// RESETTING
$('.directory_search_reset').on('click', function() {
    //hide reset button
    $('.directory_search_reset').hide();
    //clear search field
    $('.directory_search input[type="search"]').val('');
    var qsRegex;
    var buttonFilter;
    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        filter: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
            var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
            return searchResult && buttonResult;
        }
    });
    $('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope();
    });
    // use value of search field to filter
    var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
        qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
        $grid.isotope();
    }));
    // change active class on buttons
    $('.directory_menu ul').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $( this ).addClass('active');
        });
    });
    // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
        var timeout;
        threshold = threshold || 100;
        return function debounced() {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            var args = arguments;
            var _this = this;
            function delayed() {
                fn.apply( _this, args );
            }
            timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
        };
    }
});

$('.directory_search input[type="search"]').keyup(function() {
    $('.directory_search_reset').show();
});
```

===========================================================================

**EDIT**

Finally figured out how to accomplish what I was seeking.  Here is the code below:

```
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
        var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
        return searchResult && buttonResult;
    }
});
$('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope();
});
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
}));
// change active class on buttons
$('.directory_menu ul').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $( this ).addClass('active');
    });
});
// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
        var args = arguments;
        var _this = this;
        function delayed() {
            fn.apply( _this, args );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
    };
}

// RESETTING
$('.directory_search_reset').on('click', function() {
    //hide reset button
    $('.directory_search_reset').hide();
    //clear search field
    $('.directory_search input[type="search"]').val('');
    var qsRegex;
    var buttonFilter;
    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        filter: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
            var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
            return searchResult && buttonResult;
        }
    });
    $('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope();
    });
    // use value of search field to filter
    var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
        qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
        $grid.isotope();
    }));
    // change active class on buttons
    $('.directory_menu ul').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $( this ).addClass('active');
        });
    });
    // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
        var timeout;
        threshold = threshold || 100;
        return function debounced() {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            var args = arguments;
            var _this = this;
            function delayed() {
                fn.apply( _this, args );
            }
            timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
        };
    }
    **$('li').removeClass('active'); //ADDED
    $('li:first-of-type').addClass('active'); //ADDED**
});
//show reset icon once input field has been typed in
$('.directory_search input[type="search"]').keyup(function() {
    $('.directory_search_reset').show();
});
```

**Now my question is this: Is there a way to shorten all this code up?  Right now, I've duplicated most of everything as it was needed to make things work under the  `.directory_search_reset` function...but I feel like there should be a way to shorten all this up.  Is this possible?**

Comment: Please see EDIT section to original post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I at least figured out how to accomplish my initial question, here is the answer for those who have stopped by here with relatively the same (or the same) question:

```
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
        var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
        return searchResult && buttonResult;
    }
});
$('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope();
});
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
}));
// change active class on buttons
$('.directory_menu ul').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $( this ).addClass('active');
    });
});
// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
        var args = arguments;
        var _this = this;
        function delayed() {
            fn.apply( _this, args );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
    };
}

// RESETTING
$('.directory_search_reset').on('click', function() {
    //hide reset button
    $('.directory_search_reset').hide();
    //clear search field
    $('.directory_search input[type="search"]').val('');
    var qsRegex;
    var buttonFilter;
    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.directory').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.listing, .listing_title, .listing_notice', // IMPORTANT CLASSES HERE -- '.listing = container for website link', '.listing_title = container for website link title', '.listing_notice = Notice to inform there is no website under this category'
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        filter: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
            var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
            return searchResult && buttonResult;
        }
    });
    $('.directory_menu ul').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope();
    });
    // use value of search field to filter
    var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
        qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
        $grid.isotope();
    }));
    // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
        var timeout;
        threshold = threshold || 100;
        return function debounced() {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            var args = arguments;
            var _this = this;
            function delayed() {
                fn.apply( _this, args );
            }
            timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
        };
    }
    $('li').removeClass('active'); //ADDED
    $('li:first-of-type').addClass('active'); //ADDED
});
//show reset icon once input field has been typed in
$('.directory_search input[type="search"]').keyup(function() {
    $('.directory_search_reset').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to avoid replicating your code. 
The filtering is triggered when a keyup is detected in your input. 
So you just need to add one line of code which simulate that.

```js
// RESETTING
$('.directory_search_reset').on('click', function() {
  //hide reset button
  $('.directory_search_reset').hide();
  //clear search field
  $('.directory_search input[type="search"]').val('');
  $('.directory_search input[type="search"]').keyup();
})
```